# How to set a varying precision in axis labels in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to set a varying precision in the axis label, such that there are only two significant figures in the label. For example, the axis labels may be 0.20, 0.40, 0.60, 0.80, 1.0, 1.2, ect.

```
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,

    /tikz/.cd}
```

Comment: `fixed, precision=2`

Comment: @percusse That will always give 2 decimal places, though (0.20, 0.40, 0.60, 0.80, 1.00, 1.20, ...)

Comment: ah true sorry, I misread your specs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally there is the `fixed relative` key which in principle would do what you want. But unfortunately - as it is written in the manual - this key ignores the `zerofill` key, so there will be no trailing zeros at the numbers (see x axis labels in the MWE).

But we can use `siunitx` to print the numbers and there your needs work fine. Only the zero itself is printed as "0." that is why I added a special handler for that.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    % v1.14
\usepackage{siunitx}     % v2.6s
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin=-1.2,
            ymax=1.2,
            ytick distance=0.2,
            % -------------------------------------------------------------
            % change number format of `x tick label's
            x tick label style={
                /pgf/number format/.cd,
                    % using `fixed relative' would normally work ...
                    fixed relative,
                    precision=2,
                    % ... but `zerofill' is ignored for the `fixed relative'
                    % key, so here it will not give the desired result
                    zerofill,
                /tikz/.cd,
            },
            % -------------------------------------------------------------
            % change `yticklabel' to fit your needs
            yticklabel={
                % use special handler for "0.", because this gives an undesired
                % result with `\num' (see below)
                % (I assume that this strange behavior is a bug)
                \ifdim\tick pt=0pt
                    % Therefore use the "normal" tikz features to plot "0"
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[
                        fixed,
                        precision=2,
                        zerofill,
                    ]{\tick}
                \else
                    % and use `\num' for all other numbers
                    \num[
                        round-mode=figures,
                        round-precision=2,
                    ]{\tick}
                \fi
            },
            % -------------------------------------------------------------
        ]
            \addplot {x};

            \sisetup{
                round-mode=figures,
                round-precision=2,
                add-decimal-zero=true,      % <-- default
            }
            \draw (axis cs:0,0)
                % without trailing decimal separator
                node [above,green!80!black] {\num{0}}
                % with trailing decimal separator
                node [below,red!80!black]   {\num{0.}}  % same for `0.0'
            ;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: For the record: I've added a feature request to the [tikz/pgf tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/102/) that `fixed relative` also accounts for the `zerofill` key.